# Assigning a dictionary of type [String:AnyObject] to [String: String] gives nil error

Tags: ios, dictionary, swift3, null, forced-unwrapping

Hey I am newbie in Swift & IOS development. I am facing an issue searched a lot. But didn't got any solution.
I have dictionary of type [String: AnyObject] and wants to assign it to an other dictionary of type [String:String]. Xcode Shows an error which is this "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional val"
I tripled checked there is no nil value. Below here is my  code snippet
Dictionary is here

```
        let dictFormData = ["name": endorsement.name,
                            "designation":endorsement.designation,
                            "location": endorsement.location,
                            "region": endorsement.region,
                            "effectiveDateString":endorsement.effectiveDate,
                            "marriageDateString": "ss" ,
                            "genderId": String(format: "%ld", selectedGenderLookUpId),
                            "relationId": String(format: "%ld", selectedRelationLookUpId),
                            "plan": "ss",
                            "employeeId": AICLPolicyModel.getSelectedPolicy()?.employeeID as Any,
                            "requestTypeId": 35,
                            "policyId": AICLPolicyModel.getSelectedPolicy()?.policyID as Any,
                            "isEmployee": isemployee,
                            "filePath":"ss",
                            "fileName": "ss",
                            "empRemarks": endorsement.remarks,
                            "hrRemarks": "ss",
                            "adminRemarks": "ss",
                            "memberCode": AICLPolicyModel.getSelectedPolicy()?.memberCode as Any,
                            "requestStatusId": 32,
                            "customerId":  AICLPolicyModel.getSelectedPolicy()?.clientID as Any
                        ]
```

Here is assigning of one dictionary to other.

```
   let formData = (dictFormData as? [String : String])!
```

At this line it shows error once again I am quite sure there is no nil value.

Answer (score 2):

A dictionary of type `[String:AnyObject]` cannot be downcast to `[String:String]` since the types are incompatible.

Therefore `dictFormData as? [String:String]` evaluates to `nil` because the conditional downcast fails - you are then force unwrapping this `nil` with `!` and you get a crash.

You are clearly putting non-String values into `dictFormData`, so you won't be able to use a simple downcast to get a `[String:String]` dictionary.

Comment: thanks for your response I got it.  And its requirement to add non-string values. I won't able to use Simple down casting , is there any other way or complex down casting methods available

Comment: If you can't restrict the values to a single type then you will need to use `[String:Any]` (which is what you already have).   If your dictionary was `[String:AnyObject]` then you wouldn't be able to store value types, such as 32.  You could iterate through the keys and copy only the string values to a `[String:String]` dictionary, but you would lose the non-string values